# Insert into two tables with foreign key on one button click

Tags: java, mysql, database

Can I get help with inserting into two tables with foreign keys?
I have this already and when I click for the "first time" it works, but when I try for the second or after the first time, the foreign key doesn't change, it remains the same.

My database tables:

```
passenger (name, p_id) // p_id is auto-increment
luggage (lug_id, brand, type, p_id)
```

This is my code so far:

```
private void InsertLuggageInfo() {    
conn = jdbcDBconnection.ConnectDB();
        String query_luggage, query_passenger;    
query_passenger = "INSERT INTO passenger (name) VALUES (?)";
stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(query_passenger);
stmt1.setString(1, txtFirstname.getText());    
stmt1.execute();
            stmt1.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }  
try {
String p_id = null;    
            String p_id_query = "SELECT p_id FROM passenger WHERE name = '" + txtFirstname.getText() + "'";
            stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(p_id_query);
            rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();
            if (rs2.next()) {
                p_id = rs2.getString("p_id");
            }    
query_luggage = "INSERT INTO luggage (lug_id, brand, type, p_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";    
stmt3 = conn.prepareStatement(query_luggage);    
stmt2.setString(1, txtLugNr.getText());
            stmt2.setString(2, txtbrand.getText());
            stmt2.setString(3, txtType.getText());
            stmt2.setString(4, p_id);
stmt2.execute();
            stmt2.close();
}catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
```

Comment: `rs2.getString("passenger_id");` -- If the column is named `p_id` why do you use `passenger_id` here?

Comment: sorry, my bad, it is indeed p_id

Comment: If you retyped the code into StackOverflow instead of copy/pasting then we cannot be certain what we are seeing is what is actually running. Also, you have not provided any error message or stack trace (if any), nor shown the data you are using that results in the problem.  Without a lot more detail we cannot help you.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for details.

Comment: Please write exact code you are using as above code still is not correct. Variable stmt2 and stmt3 are confusing.

Comment: Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I'm really sorry, i will make sure it won't happen again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should change the way you get the generated ID. There are lots of John Smith and it could give you problem.
You can use `stmt1.getGeneratedKeys()`, as following:

```
int affectedRows = stmt1.executeUpdate();

if (affectedRows == 0) {
    throw new SQLException("Insert Passenger error: no rows were affected.");
}

try (ResultSet generatedKeys = stmt1.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
        user.setId(generatedKeys.getLong(1));
    }
    else {
        throw new SQLException("Insert Passenger error: no ID obtained.");
    }
}
```

This will garantee you get the new inserted data ID (your passenger FK).

Second: your `stmt3` is your **INSERT luggage**. But you are setting values and executing `stmt2` again.